# Dc motor speed measurement issue

Tags: stm32, encoder, brushed-dc-motor, rotor-speed

My setup is E6B2 incremental encoder(1000pr),Stm32 nucleo-l452re-p.I'm trying to measure speed for system identification and my graphs are looking kinda odd.[image]

[image]

I tried to increase the gab "Te" but the result is not good ...
[image]

I have an acquisition period of 0.0005 seconds;
I'm using the included encoder mode to interface the encoder .
If any of you have a suggestion let me know , it would help me a lot

Comment: The description is very very bad, just some code that I don't understand.

Comment: How do the graphs relate to any of the variables in your code? What exactly do you think is wrong? Saying "kinda odd" is not very helpful.

Comment: Th(I) is the position from the encoder; w is the speed . First graph is the pwm procentage , second is speed and third is position. What I mean by odd is that the speed decreases when the pwm is at 100. That does not happen in reality

Comment: Could you label the axes on your graphs? What code are you using to read the pulses from the encoder? Are you using A,B, or Z, or some combination?

Comment: I'm using the included encoder mode in cube ide T1( A) . I'm getting rising edge increments from the counter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is velocity measurements are more susceptible to noise and the resolution of the encoder, this is especially apparent at low speeds (low speed meaning the speed of the motor relative to what the encoder can resolve).

There are two ways to look at this:

1. The motor is not spinning fast enough for the resolution of the encoder
2. The encoder needs to have more resolution if you wish to run it at low speeds.

Also slowing down the sampling of the encoder will actually *increase* velocity resolution. Another thing you could try is down-sample the position vector and then take the differential to get velocity.

If down sampling affects the system id then you may need a higher resolution encoder, or a different sensor that gives you velocity directly.

Another thing:

A ramp does not capture system dynamics across many frequencies, you'll want to do a sine sweep, or pulses.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will try your suggestions and come back with a feedback. The ramp that you see is the position graph. The input signal is represented in the first graph (pseudo random binary sequence ) which is known to have many harmonics inside. A missed a thing about my setup. I measure after a reductor 64:1 . The motor has 2 hall sensors inside , but that gives me less resolution than the encoder. I will try to open the motor and measure directly at the shaft . Again , thank you for the suggestions , have a great day!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: The max rpm of the motor is 140rpm if measured after de reductor. That means that the motor shaft spins at 8960 rpm. What encoder would be suitable for 140 and 8960 ? . Is there a good ratio(rpm/impulsesPerRotation)?